# SQLite: how do I fix syntax on INSERT INTO?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, insert-into

I have a column CARDNUM that I am trying to increment by +1 in a Table called TOTALCOUNT.  App crashed with syntax error near "SET"

This is my INSERT statement:

```
db.execSQL("INSERT INTO "+ DBContract.DBEntry.TABLE_NAME_TOTALCOUNT+" SET "+ DBContract.DBEntry.COLUMN_NAME_CARDNUM + "="+ DBContract.DBEntry.COLUMN_NAME_CARDNUM+"+1");
```

What am I not getting right?

```
private static final String SQL_CREATE_CARDNUM =
            "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "+ DBContract.DBEntry.TABLE_NAME_TOTALCOUNT +
            "( "+ DBContract.DBEntry.COLUMN_NAME_COUNTID +
            " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY UNIQUE , "+
            DBContract.DBEntry.COLUMN_NAME_CARDNUM +
            " INTEGER DEFAULT 1);";


// Push the database data to the RecyclerView
public List<UserData> getDataFromDB(){
    List<UserData> modelList = new ArrayList<>();        
    String query = "SELECT *,(SELECT " + DBContract.DBEntry.COLUMN_NAME_CARDNUM +
            " from " + DBContract.DBEntry.TABLE_NAME_TOTALCOUNT +") from "
            + DBContract.DBEntry.TABLE_NAME_USERINPUTS +";";

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    db.beginTransaction();

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);

        try {
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    UserData userData = new UserData();
                    userData.setTodo(cursor.getString(1));
                    userData.setNote1(cursor.getString(2));
                    userData.setNote2(cursor.getString(3));
                    userData.setDuedate(cursor.getString(4));
                    userData.setDuetime(cursor.getString(5));
                    userData.setTimestamp(cursor.getLong6));
                    userData.setCardnum(cursor.getInt(7));

                    modelList.add(0, userData);
                    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
        } finally {
              if(cursor !=null && !cursor.isClosed()){
              cursor.close();
              }
          }
    db.setTransactionSuccessful();
    db.endTransaction();
    return modelList;
}
```

The Logcat for CARDNUM shows "(SELECT cardnum from totalcount)=0.

Comment: You can't use "set" in INSERT as I know. Its there in UPDATE. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Ok but there is no UPDATE.

Comment: Check @Hello World's answer

Comment: Refer this : http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp.. Your insert query is wrong..!!

Comment: @janki gadhiya  Thank you I will check it out...but please let me know what specifically is wrong!

Comment: you have previously inserted any data and you want to Update it or ?? you want a fresh record to be inserted to the database ??

Comment: ok share your Table structure and tell me what is `DBContract.DBEntry.COLUMN_NAME_CARDNUM`.??

Comment: DBContract.DBEntry.COLUMN_NAME_CARDNUM is a column.  It is very simple.  The first row should default to 1.  Then each row created with INSERT thereafter is +1.  So the row from the start would be 1,2,3,4,5 after 4 INSERTS.

Answer (score 1):

You have an incorrect syntax for INSERT.

Refer to the following:

http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-insert
http://www.techonthenet.com/sqlite/insert.php

For example:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (
 column1,
 column2 ,..)
VALUES
 (
 value1,
 value2 ,...);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
db.execSQL("UPDATE "+ DBContract.DBEntry.TABLE_NAME_TOTALCOUNT+" SET "+ DBContract.DBEntry.COLUMN_NAME_CARDNUM + "="+ DBContract.DBEntry.COLUMN_NAME_CARDNUM+"+1");
```

It is recommended to set `id` using `WHERE` to update particular row.

Comment: I want to use the INSERT to add a new row to the column.  I thought UPDATE should only be used for editing/updating existing row data.  Please advise.

Comment: How you want to increment `CARDNUM` by 1 if row is not already exists?

Comment: The default value of CARDNUM is set to 1 when the table is created: "...COLUMN_NAME_CARDNUM +
                " INTEGER DEFAULT 1)"

Comment: In that case you have to use `INSERT` query only and set `2` as a value of `CARDNUM` column

Comment: Why 2?  And where do you set the value?  I thought the primary key was column zero and the CARDNUM column is 1, correct?

Comment: if you want to add the value of this column sequentially, add `autoincrement` to property to this column.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to increment a column using **INSERT** which can not be done. But if you still want to use **INSERT** statement then you can not use **SET** in **INSERT**.
An **INSERT** operation should look like this:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME (cloumn1_name, column2_name, column3_name) VALUES (column1_value,cloumn2_value,column3_value)
```

You can nou update a value via **INSERT** statement. If you want to update a value you must use **UPDATE** statement. In that case an **UPDATE** statement looks like this:

```
UPDATE table_name SET column1 = value1, column2 = value2...., columnN = valueN WHERE [condition];
```